# Human checks for answers made quickly

Tags: feature-request, answers, captcha

This is just a small feature request.

I understand that it's necessary to check that a poster is human when they're giving an answer if they submit the answer within a short period of time after selecting the answer box. However, would it be possible to put a reasonable reputation cap on this feature?

I often find I begin to write a comment and it slowly turns into an answer without me realising. I decide to finish writing the answer in the comment box, then just ctrl+a, ctrl+c, click the answer box, ctrl+v, submit. The problem with this approach is that the system then thinks I'm not human and I have to submit a captcha check to prove my humanity - which can be mildly annoying, as well as a little condescending. It seems unlikely to me that an account of someone with a high level of reputation on the site would be used for spamming except in the (I assume rare) case that the account has been compromised, and so I don't think this request is unreasonable.

Comment: How can *you* be sure that *you* are human? What if you're just a really good AI software?

Comment: Then I guess I'd be smart enough for the captchas too and they're still unnecessary :D.

Comment: What if you're only programmed to think that you're smart enough for that?

Comment: I am I programmed to also have an existential crisis right now?

Comment: Daniel, only artificial programs have existential crises. Humans just exist. I suggest you find your programmer and ask him to correct that...

Comment: If you think captcha is bad now, you should have seen it in the early days, see [this thread.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1160/242) The captchas will get less frequent the higher your rep.

Comment: What if Daniel Rust's programmer is just really good AI software?

Comment: According to [this MSO answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2293/214632), it appears that all you would have to do is wait **5 seconds** between clicking on the edit-box and submitting your post to avoid the captcha.  (And after reaching 10K you only have to wait 2.5 secs.)

Comment: I still get captchas sometimes, and usually the answers I write are long and not copy-pasted.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Interesting.... I honestly can't remember doing a captcha here.  I assume I had to do one on my first post, and maybe even a few more until my reputation sufficiently increased, but in the last couple years, I don't think I've gotten one.